# Node cannot read environmental variable from Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm following an introductory course on Azure Web Apps.
One specific tutorial shows how to get an environmental parameter, previously set from the Azure portal, and display it in your webpage, but this doesn't work for me.

The code is really simple and I'm only pasting the server response where the env parameter should go

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    response.write("<html>");
    response.write("<head>");
    response.write("<title>Hello</title>");
    response.write("</head>");
    response.write("<body>");
    response.write(`Hello from ${process.env.MyParameter}!`);  //PROBLEM HERE
    response.write("</body>");
    response.write("</html>");
    response.end();
});
```

Of course, I've set up a new *application setting* in my Azure app Configuration that is called *MyParameter*.
Now if I want to display some plain text such as `response.write("Hello world");` it works perfectly, but when I try to get the env variable I get a **HTTP ERROR 500 - This page isn't working** error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That seems strange to me, have you tried with `process.env["MyParameter"]` ?

Comment: Yup I tried that too. Same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> response.write(`Hello from ${process.env.MyParameter}!`);

This is not correct.

You should use

`response.write("hello from" + process.env.MyParameter);`

Comment: That fixed it!! Thanks!
The last thing I expected was a JS syntax error in the code provided by the tutorial!

Comment: @AndreaTassera - if it's content on Microsoft Docs, you can submit a fix to the tutorial.

Comment: It's on Edx. They might have a similar feature, I'll check. Good advice thanks!